# get value from an html input box in a PHP page, without reloading page

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

```
<div class="col-md-6">
     <label class="control-label"><span class="text-danger">*</span>Journey Days</label>
     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" name="day" class="form-control" >
            <?php echo $this->input->post('day');?> </input>
        <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo form_error('day');?></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

If the **name="day"** value is set then how can i get this day value ?
I want to do like this ,

```
<?php
  if (isset($day))
    { print $day ; } 
   else { print " day is not set  " ;} ?>
```

Comment: dont have any form tag here @sietse85

Answer (score 5):

To get values from input fields without having to reload the page you will have to use javascript.  Give your input tag an id like 'day'

```
<input type="number" name="day" class="form-control" id="day">
```

Use javascript to retrieve the value. Of course this code needs to be in a function which you call when changing the input.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var day = document.getElementById('day').value; </script>
```

In the end it looks something like this, the onchange event listener calls your function when the value inside the input has changed:

```
<input type="number" name="day" class="form-control" id="day" onchange="alertDay()">

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function alertDay() {
    var day = document.getElementById('day').value; 
    alert(day);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This jquery Script.

```
<input type="number" name="day" class="form-control" id="day">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

   $(document).on('change', '#day', function(){
      var day = $('#day').val(); 
      alert(day);
    });

</script>
```

You may use change or input or onkeyup. Change after click outside than run this script input every letter type and run this script onkeyup every letter type and run this script same as input.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

From this form , Now I have to get value of name="day" .

```
<script>
var dayValue= document.getELementByName("name").value 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ajax in jquery to get the value without reloading the page.